# Photos in album returning empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I've been having a recurring issue today. I'm trying to display the photos from an album. For some reason everything works fine on the Graph Explorer using graph and fql (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ) but when I pull it into the app I always get an empty array returned.

I do have the correct permissions for this request too all permissions on this app are email, user_about_me, publish_actions, user_photos

The call's I have tried that are doing this are below and they all give me the same results.

```
$photos = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos/');

// or

$photos = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos/?access_token=' . $access_token);

// or

$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT images, src FROM photo WHERE album_object_id = " . $album_id,
);

$photos = $facebook->api($params);
```

It has returned the album contents once or twice, but out of the hundreds of times i've tested this 99.99% of the time its a blank array/json coming back.

Anyone know of a similar issue with this at all.

Comment: Try enclosing the $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos/'); in a try catch and outputting the exception message:

try {
$photos = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos/');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
print_r($e->getMessage());
}

Then paste the output here so we can help you better.